# Adjusting the Document size for Adobe Illustrator CS6 files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I've read many articles on how to adjust Artboard width and height settings in Adobe Illustrator, but have not found a single article on how to adjust the width and height for the background document layer that Artboards sit on.

A single Artboard may be 1000px by 1000px, but I can still scroll for miles left and right of the Artboard.  I don't want that.  I want the background size to bthe same as my Artboard size.  How do we do that?  Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is something that can be done.  I've never had an issue with it; I actually like it.  I can keep materials to the sides, if I'm working on variants of a design.

Comment: And thats cool that we have the flexibility to do that. I find it annoying at times when I am trying to drag specific items from my artboard, but then my mouse may go off track by accident and scroll allllll the way left. As a result, it doesn't feel that the martial's are contained when that happens, and that bothers me.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I always zoom out, when moving objects out of my artboards to avoid (or minimize) the effect of any stray mouse movements.  Otherwise, I `CMD + Z` and try again.  To navigate, I always use the spacebar and mouse combo to click and drag around, so maybe that's another reason that I haven't had any real issues with over-scrolling.

Comment: I second space bar usage. Usually much more useful for moving around. 

(Hmm, I wonder what drinks they serve in a space bar? Cosmonauts perhaps.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible. The workspace is the workspace, and you can't resize it. To alleviate your scroll problems, you might want to try <kbd>Ctrl / Option</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, which will make your current artboard fully visible on-screen.

Comment: Thank you Vincent for the extra tip, along with the absolute truth.  I know now what I have to deal with.

Comment: Very useful shortcut.
I'll also add that that huge pasteboard is excellent for mocking up ideas. As there's not really much in the way of a history panel, many of us just duplicate objects or sets of objects as we go and leave a trail of 'sketches' in this area. Then there's multiple art boards. Oh and it's also handy having such a large pasteboard when you want the arc of a very large circle, for example.